# Java compiler error: Can't open input server /Library/InputManagers/Inquisitor

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, java

I am trying to compile HelloWorld in Java under Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and I get this compiler error:

> java[51692:903] Can't open input server /Library/InputManagers/Inquisitor

It happens when I am using terminal command `javac` and when I am trying to do this in NetBeans.
I was trying to open folder "Inquisitor", but I have no access to folder, even if I login as root user.

What is going on?

Comment: How was this off-topic on SO?

Comment: @Hassan Running a compiler in an odd (configured wrong, outdated) environment is not a programming question.

Comment: Please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28926900/1702557). Maybe `Inquisitor` need to be updated. Please check the version and compare if it is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `Application` → `Utilities` → `Terminal.app`:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Library/InputManagers/Inquisitor
```

Where 777 are read/write/execute flags for all users for all files in director `/Library/InputManagers/Inquisitor`. Explained [here](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/chmod/).

Answer (score -2):

Try removing it:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/InputManagers/Inquisitor/
```

Comment: -1: Not necessarily a good idea to go around removing stuff you think might be causing a problem.